# What is the implicit type of a localparam constant?

Tags: system-verilog

Coming from a VHDL background, I'm a bit confused about SystemVerilog's implicit declaration typing. For example, in the following definition, what's the underlying type of the `UNFUSIBLES_RANGE_BYTES` constant?

```
localparam UNFUSIBLES_RANGE_BYTES = 64'd9223372036854773764;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 6.20.4 *Local parameters (localparam)*:

> Local parameters are identical to parameters except ...

The "except" is irrelevant to your question.  So, refer to section 6.20.2 *Value parameters*.  Since your declaration does not have a *type* specification or a *range* specification, this applies:

> A parameter declaration with no type or range specification shall
> default to the type and range of the final value assigned to the
> parameter, after any value overrides have been applied. If the
> expression is real, the parameter is real. If the expression is
> integral, the parameter is a `logic` vector of the same size with range
> `[size-1:0]`.

This means `UNFUSIBLES_RANGE_BYTES` is a 64-bit integral `logic` vector.